# Force Uninstall Symantec Endpoint Protection 11?

Tags: anti-virus, uninstall, ms-security-essentials, sep

Symantec Endpoint Protection 11 blue-screen-of-deathed my computer.
I was unable remove S.E.P. (Symantec Endpoint Protection) while booted in safe mode so I simply disabled all related services, and then followed the manual uninstallation guide.

Even though it's not listed in the add/remove programs area I'm assuming it's still not fully uninstalled, because currently I can't turn on real time protection in Microsoft Security Essentials, and people say that it could be because another antivirus is interfering. How can I fully get rid of S.E.P.?

Comment: Symantec is a company, not a product. Do you mean Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes.

Comment: What procedure exactly did you follow?

Comment: I got into safe mode because normal would BSOD. First I tried to remove it though Uninstall Programs and Features. Didn't work. Then I followed someone's guide to stop BSOD by disabling all services by Symantec. Rebooted and was able to get into normal mode fine. Tried to uninstall again. No luck. Tried to follows manual removal guide. Removed tons of registry keys and what not. Then ran CleanWipe. Then AppRemover(only found Malwarebytes and MSE). Now I'm here.

Comment: Perhaps it's Malwarebytes, and not SEP that is interfering with MSE.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with some issues like this on a clients workstation before. We needed a utility called CleanWipe which is only legitimately obtained from their support after opening a ticket (It might have changed). I found the following link which explains a little more about the CleanWipe tool and obtaining it
http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/how-get-cleanwipe-tool-endpoint-removal

Comment: I got cleanwipe. Ran it. Didn't solve the issue. Still can't turn on MSE real time protection nor install new Endpoint Protection. I'm going mad here.

Comment: Wow, that is annoying. What error message do you receive when you try to turn on MSE RTP? Is there anything relating to this in the event log? go to start -> Run -> MSConfig and make sure nothing related to Symantec is enabled in the start-up sections, reboot and try again. Also, run this http://www.appremover.com/ and see if anything from symantec appears.

Comment: I get this: "RTP couldn't be turned on. The operation returned because the timeout period expired. Error code: 0x800705b4"